# Как компилятор понимает что count - это кол-во вводимых чисел

Tags: java

```
public class Average {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        float sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
            int number = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            if (number != -1) {
                sum = number + sum;
                count++;
            }
            else if (number == -1)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(sum/count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что при каждом новом вводе к count прибавляется 1 : `count++`

Answer (score 2):

Потому что на каждой итерации цикла `while` значение `count` увеличивается на единицу вплоть до момента, пока очередное число не будет равно `-1`. При этом на каждой итерации `while` считывается ровно одно число.

В результате "`count` = кол-во итераций = кол-во чисел" (без учета `-1`).

Также код можно написать несколько короче, если использовать `Scanner` и проверку на `-1` в самом `while`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;
int number;
while ((number = scanner.nextInt()) != -1)
{
    sum += number;
    count++;
}
System.out.println(1.0 * sum / count);
```